# Share Netty NioEventLoopGroup between Lettuce & AsyncHttpClient

Tags: redis, netty, asynchttpclient

My application is using Netty 4.1.6.Final and [Lettuce 4.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/biz.paluch.redis/lettuce/4.3.0.Final), [Async Http Client 2.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.1.0-alpha1)

[Lettuce](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/biz.paluch.redis/lettuce/4.3.0.Final) 4.3.0 also relies on netty 4.1.6.Final.
[Async Http Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.1.0-alpha1) 4.3.0 also relies on netty 4.1.4.Final.

Now I see Lettuce creates its thread pool.  Async Http Client also creates its thread pool. And my application creates another thread pool for Netty.

Is it possible to share the same `NioEventLoopGroup` cross all the component to reduce thread number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Async Http Client

```
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setEventLoopGroup(myEventGroup).build())
```

### Lettuce

Add `RedisEventLoopGroupProvider` class

```
public class RedisEventLoopGroupProvider extends DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider {


    public RedisEventLoopGroupProvider() {
        super(3);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends EventLoopGroup> T allocate(Class<T> type) {
        if (NioEventLoopGroup.class.equals(type)) {
            return (T)myEventGroup;
        }
        return super.allocate((Class<T>)type);
    }

}
```

Initialize in this way

```
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create( DefaultClientResources.builder()
            .eventLoopGroupProvider(new RedisEventLoopGroupProvider())
            .ioThreadPoolSize(1)
            .computationThreadPoolSize(3)
            .build(), Environment.REDIS_CONNECTION);
```